# Numpy: Sum two 1D arrays to get a 2D array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two 1D arrays (a and b) and I want to sum them element-wise to create a 2D array (c). The 2D array has dimension (n,m) where n is the length of a and m is the length of b. The precise relation goes as:
c[i][j] = a[i]+b[j], where i runs from 0 to n-1 and j runs from 0 to m-1.
For example, consider the following code

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([1,2])
c = a+b
```

This code gives me broadcasting error. The goal is to get c = [[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]. Obviously we can use a loop to get every element of c, but I am looking for a way to do this without going through a loop.

Comment: Create a new axis. For `(a + b).shape == (3, 2)`, we require that `a.shape == (3, 1)` and `b.shape == (1, 2)`.

Comment: Can you write a short code that does this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For

```
(u + v).shape == (3, 2)
```

, we require:

```
u.shape == (3, 1)
v.shape == (1, 2)
```

Thus, the easiest way to accomplish this is by creating a new axis:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([1, 2])
c = a[..., np.newaxis] + b[np.newaxis, ...]
```

Comment: I think it is useful to mention [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: I think this is working! Can you update your answer to the following code (for future reference)?
`a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([1,2])

c = a[:,np.newaxis]+b[np.newaxis,:]

print(c)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to `tile` your arrays using the length of the other array.
Note that I take the transpose of `np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))` with `.T`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([1,2])
c = np.tile(a, (len(b), 1)) + np.tile(b, (len(a), 1)).T
```

hope it helps